# How to record audio of remotepeer webrtc in Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to record the remote peer's audio but can't,
The record local peer I did it through this class
https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/androidapp/src/org/appspot/apprtc/RecordedAudioToFileController.java

How to get data buffer of audio (remote) in webrtc Android

Comment: Same question, have you found solution yet?